# NetBeans 7.2, starting a maven spring project and add hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven, netbeans

I'm trying to move to maven as build system in order to have a more standard management of dependencies.

This are the steps I do and the simple, (maven newbie) questions I ask. The process is the most straightforward i can immagine, so this issues should be very easy to reproduce.

1. Let start with File, New Project, Maven, Web Application. 
   In the following forms, i keep all the defaults but for the application server field where I've choosen "Apache Tomcat 7.0.11.0". 
   I notice that this wizard does not propose any Framework (Sring, Hibernate and so on), while the standard non-maven project creation wizard do allow the choiche of the frameworks to include.

If we have a look at the project now, here is what we see:

[image]


**So the first question is: why spring is already included, even before that i've explicitly added it?**

Let have a look at the project properties: 
[image]

So no frameworks are selected. 
I want to use spring just for its dependency injection container (and at a later time i perhaps eill add spring security, but this is not a priority in this moment). **Do i need to add it again since, as I said above, some core modules are already included?**

2. In the project properties, in the framework node, i add Hibernate and I chose a database connection. The dependencies now become as follows.

[image]

Two of them (I've highlighted them in the screenshot) are marked as "Dependency not yet downloaded. Build project to correct errors" (you can see this message as a hint when you move the pointer over them). I've build the project but the error still remain.
In the output of maven i see:

```
Failed to execute goal on project CreatingMavenSpringProject: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.mycompany:CreatingMavenSpringProject:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT: The following artifacts could not be resolved: javax.sql:jdbc-stdext:jar:2.0, javax.transaction:jta:jar:1.0.1B: Could not find artifact javax.sql:jdbc-stdext:jar:2.0 in unknown-jars-temp-repo (file:C:\Users\agostino\Documents\NetBeansProjects\CreatingMavenSpringProject/lib) -> [Help 1]

To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
```

I've tried as it suggested:

```
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal o
n project CreatingMavenSpringProject: Could not resolve dependencies for project
 com.mycompany:CreatingMavenSpringProject:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT: The following artifa
cts could not be resolved: javax.sql:jdbc-stdext:jar:2.0, javax.transaction:jta:
jar:1.0.1B: Failure to find javax.sql:jdbc-stdext:jar:2.0 in file:C:\Users\agost
ino\Documents\NetBeansProjects\CreatingMavenSpringProject/lib was cached in the
local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval o
f unknown-jars-temp-repo has elapsed or updates are forced
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.getDe
pendencies(LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:210)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.resol
veProjectDependencies(LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:117)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.ensureDependenciesAr
eResolved(MojoExecutor.java:258)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor
.java:201)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor
.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor
.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProje
ct(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProje
ct(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBu
ild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(Lifecycl
eStarter.java:161)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Laun
cher.java:290)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.jav
a:230)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(La
uncher.java:409)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:
352)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.project.DependencyResolutionException: Could not res
olve dependencies for project com.mycompany:CreatingMavenSpringProject:war:1.0-S
NAPSHOT: The following artifacts could not be resolved: javax.sql:jdbc-stdext:ja
r:2.0, javax.transaction:jta:jar:1.0.1B: Failure to find javax.sql:jdbc-stdext:j
ar:2.0 in file:C:\Users\agostino\Documents\NetBeansProjects\CreatingMavenSpringP
roject/lib was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempte
d until the update interval of unknown-jars-temp-repo has elapsed or updates are
 forced
        at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.resolve(D
efaultProjectDependenciesResolver.java:189)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.getDe
pendencies(LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:185)
        ... 22 more
Caused by: org.sonatype.aether.resolution.DependencyResolutionException: The fol
lowing artifacts could not be resolved: javax.sql:jdbc-stdext:jar:2.0, javax.tra
nsaction:jta:jar:1.0.1B: Failure to find javax.sql:jdbc-stdext:jar:2.0 in file:C
:\Users\agostino\Documents\NetBeansProjects\CreatingMavenSpringProject/lib was c
ached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the upda
te interval of unknown-jars-temp-repo has elapsed or updates are forced
        at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveDepe
ndencies(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:375)
        at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.resolve(D
efaultProjectDependenciesResolver.java:183)
        ... 23 more
Caused by: org.sonatype.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: The follo
wing artifacts could not be resolved: javax.sql:jdbc-stdext:jar:2.0, javax.trans
action:jta:jar:1.0.1B: Failure to find javax.sql:jdbc-stdext:jar:2.0 in file:C:\
Users\agostino\Documents\NetBeansProjects\CreatingMavenSpringProject/lib was cac
hed in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update
 interval of unknown-jars-temp-repo has elapsed or updates are forced
        at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(Def
aultArtifactResolver.java:538)
        at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArti
facts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:216)
        at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveDepe
ndencies(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:358)
        ... 24 more
Caused by: org.sonatype.aether.transfer.ArtifactNotFoundException: Failure to fi
nd javax.sql:jdbc-stdext:jar:2.0 in file:C:\Users\agostino\Documents\NetBeansPro
jects\CreatingMavenSpringProject/lib was cached in the local repository, resolut
ion will not be reattempted until the update interval of unknown-jars-temp-repo
has elapsed or updates are forced
        at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultUpdateCheckManager.newExcept
ion(DefaultUpdateCheckManager.java:230)
        at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultUpdateCheckManager.checkArti
fact(DefaultUpdateCheckManager.java:204)
        at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(Def
aultArtifactResolver.java:427)
        ... 26 more
```

**And now I'm stuck at this point, please notice that this is the out-of-the-box behavior of a maven project when you try to add hibernate. How to fix this?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Tomcat 7.0.27 I don't see the first problem (the Spring dependencies) but I can duplicate the second problem (can't download depdencies). Checking the `pom.xml` I see it has errors such as this dependency:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>unknown.binary</groupId>
    <artifactId>derbyclient</artifactId>
    <version>SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

and this repository:

```xml
<repository>
    <id>unknown-jars-temp-repo</id>
    <name>A temporary repository created by NetBeans for libraries and jars it 
    could not identify. Please replace the dependencies in this repository with 
    correct ones and delete this repository.</name>
    <url>file:${project.basedir}/lib</url>
</repository>
```

Even though the Netbeans wiki pages show examples of framework selection with Maven projects I'd recommend adding dependencies from the "Add dependency..." option of the "Dependencies" node.

**Edit:** Added `pom.xml` errors after repeating the same steps in a different machine.

Comment: @AgostinoX I've added two.

Answer (score 3):

You can manually modify the POM file by adding the following repository under repositories section:

```
<repositories>
   ...
   <repository>
      <id>java.net-m2</id>
      <name>java.net - Maven 2</name>
      <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/java.net-m2</url>
   </repository>
</repositories>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can always download the dependencies manually.
For example you can download
 - jdbc-stdext-2.0.jar from http://download.java.net/maven/2/javax/sql/jdbc-stdext/2.0/jdbc-stdext-2.0.jar
 - jta-1.0.1B.jar from http://download.java.net/maven/2/javax/transaction/jta/1.0.1B/jta-1.0.1B.jar

then put the jars in the correct location in your .m2 repository.
 - .m2/repository/javax/sql/jdbc-stdext/2.0/jdbc-stdext-2.0.jar
 - .m2/repository/javax/transaction/jta/1.0.1B/jta-1.0.1B.jar

then run maven clean and build.

Comment: downvoted because it is a big antipattern to manually download libraries and put them into your local maven repo, this way the build will run only on your local machine, and everyone else (including your CI server) will have the same problem again - why then use Maven in the first place?
Better add the repository and let Maven do its work correctly, as suggested in the answer by @endru